# Issues installing molden on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install molden on my machine (I have had it previously but needed to reinstall the OS) but keep getting a weird error. I am not able to understand it or solve it on my own. Any help will be great. 
Below is the error I get when I run `make`:

```
    {xwin.c:(.text+0x9b52b): undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
xwin.c:(.text+0x9b53d): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
xwin.c:(.text+0x9b585): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:262: recipe for target 'gmolden' failed
make: *** [gmolden] Error 1
 }
```

Comment: See this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116422/problematic-installation-of-molden-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Searching on `manpages.ubuntu.com` for `glGenTextures` takes one to [the glGenTextures `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/glGenTextures.3G.html), which says that `glGenTextures` is part of `OpenGL`. `apt search OpenGL` will show you packages to install, prefer the ones with the `-dev` suffix.