# Problematic Installation of MOLDEN on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Molden5.9 on Ubuntu, but I am encountering this error:

```
enter code heref77 -g -m64  -c -o atomdens.o atomdens.f
make: f77: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'atomdens.o' failed
make: *** [atomdens.o] Error 127
```

I am following the procedure reported on the official website [molden](http://cheminf.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/howtoget.html)

Comment: how are you installing it?

Comment: I download it, un-tar it. Then i go into the folder and when i try to “make” i get the error.

Comment: I am very naively following what is written on the website

Comment: edit your comment and add in the website you are using

Comment: Seems like the fortran compiler is missing, try: `sudo apt-get install gfortran` Follow this guidelines to satisfy all necessary dependencies on the website: http://cheminf.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/linux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this pointers to satisfy the requirements to install molden from source: [Pointers for installing Molden from source](http://cheminf.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/linux.html)

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran libX11-6 libX11-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev build-essential mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxmu-dev makedepend xutils-dev wget
```